# Books request on nonlinear recurrence relations.

Tags: recurrences, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hi, do you have some sort of a bibliography on advanced techniques in recurrence equations, such as nonlinear ones and others?

As I see it recurrence equations are quite similar to differential equations.

Obviously we can go from ODE to a recurrence relation by plugging suitable power series solution to the ODE, but can I also reverse this proccess; i.e, have a recurrence relation and then find a suitable ODE for this relation, is this always the case?

Thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rather old book by Levy and Lessman, Finite Difference Equations.